# Error Deserializing XML Document 1,2

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm having trouble de-serializing an XML document.

```
<rules version="61">
    <emie>
        <domain exclude="false">facebook.com</domain>
        <domain exclude="false">google.com</domain>
        <domain exclude="false">bbc.co.uk</domain>
    </emie>
    <docMode>
        <domain docMode="7">outlook.com</domain>
        <domain docMode="7">yahoo.com</domain>
    </docMode>
</rules>
```

I've copied and pasted into visual studio - using the Paste XML as class and that's created the following class

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class rules
    {

        private rulesDomain[] emieField;

        private rulesDomain1[] docModeField;

        private byte versionField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("domain", IsNullable = false)]
        public rulesDomain[] emie
        {
            get
            {
                return this.emieField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.emieField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("domain", IsNullable = false)]
        public rulesDomain1[] docMode
        {
            get
            {
                return this.docModeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.docModeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public byte version
        {
            get
            {
                return this.versionField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.versionField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class rulesDomain
    {

        private bool excludeField;

        private string valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public bool exclude
        {
            get
            {
                return this.excludeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.excludeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class rulesDomain1
    {

        private string docModeField;

        private string valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string docMode
        {
            get
            {
                return this.docModeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.docModeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I then run the following code to deserialise

```
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlSerializer));
            Classes.rules r;

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"file.xml"))
            {
                r = (Classes.rules)mySerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
```

It's errors on the line r =... {" was not expected."}

I'm pretty certain the error lies in the class and the declarations at the top but I haven't been able to change it so it works, could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlSerializer));
```

to

```
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Classes.rules));
```

Its parameter is type of the object that this XmlSerializer can serialize.

Comment: Doh - I completely missed that. That fixed it, thank you for the really quick response.